Can't get existing JMS message from DLQ on Payara 5.2022.5
I'm trying to reprocess messages from the dead letter/message queue (DLQ).
In the method below I'm getting null when I do dlqConsumer.receive(5000) on Payara 5.2022.5.  Where as when I used a QueueBrowser, the messages display fine.  What does the while loop not execute?
public void resubmitMessages(int toResubmit) throws Exception {
    log.debug("DLQService: resubmitMessages()");
    InitialContext ctx = null;
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    QueueConnection queueConn = null;

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
        queueConn = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(true, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        assert queueSession.getTransacted();

        Queue clsQueue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(CLS_NAME);
        QueueSender sender = queueSession.createSender(clsQueue);

        Queue dlq = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/mq.sys.dmq");
        MessageConsumer dlqConsumer = queueSession.createConsumer(dlq);

        int i = 0;
        Message message;
        while ((message = dlqConsumer.receive(5000)) != null && i < toResubmit) {
            try {
                log.debug("Processing: " + ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject());
                sender.send(message);
                queueSession.commit();
                log.debug("resubmitted successfully to main queue from dlq");
            } catch (JMSException jmse) {
                log.error("Exception caught while resubmitting message to main queue", jmse);
                queueSession.rollback();
                throw jmse;
            }
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception caught while sending message", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        cleanUp(ctx, queueConn);
    }
}


I was missing queueConn.start(); to start the transaction.  Why the way I had it, it did not return a message, I have no idea.  If you are a JMS expert, please comment on this.
